Connecting remotely to PostgreSQL Database - Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired
I am trying to establish a basic connection to my PostgreSQL database. I want this connection to be remote not just through local network. This is the following I did:
I made sure that in postgresql.conf I had this line
listen_addresses = '*'

Then in pg_hba.conf at the end of the file I added this line
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5

I am using Windows so in Windows Firewall I added a new rule to allow TCP remote connections through port 5432, the default port that I have set for PostgreSQL.

On my remote computer using PG Admin 4, in the connection settings to register a new server, I put for
Host name/address: my database's laptop's public ip4 address
Port: 5432
Maintenance database: postgres
Username: postgres
Password: my admin account's password

I hit Save, and get the error
 Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired


use an encrypted vpn like ssh,. never ever leave a open port to the internet, all ranges are repetatly scannneed and attackeed if a port is open


Did you restart the server after making the postgresql.conf change and reload it after the pg_hba.conf change?  2) Is there a firewall upstream of you laptop, a router for instance? 3) FYI, this host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5 is not a good thing to have in an internet accessible Postgres instance.


This is a firewall problem. Probably one built into your modem/router.

Thanks guys, I'll check my firewall in my modem.
@nbk

@nbk, can you give me more info on what you are talking about? I should only attempt to connect to my database on a secure VPN?

most routers have a openvpn server installed and explain how to use it. or you can do https://homenetworkguy.com/how-to/configure-openvpn-opnsense/   or https://www.hackster.io/carpi/ssh-port-forwarding-for-remote-device-access-behind-firewall-1f4c2d

If you properly restarted PostgreSQL after changing listen_addresses, it must be a network problem.
